# finding whether request is for post, and post id

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, posts

I need a hook such that when visitor lands on any of the post **(not page)**, I need to record a hit.

How can I find whether the request is for post, and is there any hook to find if the loaded content is post, and if yes, what is post id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will work:

```
function record_hit_if_post(){
    global $wp_query;
    if($wp_query->is_single==1)
        // single post's ID:
        // $wp_query->post->ID;
}
add_filter('template_redirect', 'record_hit_if_post');
```

Comment: is_single might come up with page too, don't you think so?

Comment: no, just single post. is_page == 1 on a page